# Substitution for differential equations with Mathics in Python

Tags: python, sympy, differential-equations, mathics

For a project dealing with differential equations, I would like to replace all the variables `"y"` of my differential equation with another expression, like the `sympy.subs()` method actually does.

However, I want to get totally rid of Sympy and only use Mathics.
Is this possible? I started to look into `Rule` and `Pattern` classes, but I didn't really understand.

Here's an example of what I expect :

```py
session = MathicsSession()

x = Symbol("x")
y = Symbol("y")

eq1str = "Derivative[y, {x, 2}] + 100 * y"
eq1 = session.evaluate(eq1str).to_python()

eq2str = "cos(x) + x**2"
eq2 = session.evaluate(eq2str).to_python()

#Here: in "eq1" replace "y" by "eq2
```